# Why google map in primefaces is not displayed many times in one session in the different chrome tabs for two similar requests?

Tags: google-maps, session, primefaces

I have deployed my application on the Tomcat Server and find that map is displayed only ones for active session. If I open new tab in chrome and paste the same url like for active session in the previous tab - google map is not displayed in the new tab. Also if I close browser and session is live I have the same result - map can't be displayed.
What I must to do to fix this problem?

Map is displayed by next code

```
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"
            type="text/javascript" />
```

Example
[image]

Comment: on the local machine i found this mistake from the server Jun 10, 2016 3:51:36 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, undefined/undefined.js, from library, primefaces. Wha can it be wit primefaces? I use primefaces 5.3

Comment: I have found that there is no problem when i remove binding="#{mapBean.gMap}". But i need link to map object in my bean.
Why such problem is presernt in binding?

Comment: See [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and also search stackoverflow about binding problems

Comment: I have found answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378153/binding-of-pgmap-component-doesnt-work-primefaces-3-4-1
by adding <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="gmap/gmap.js" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found answer here [binding of <p:gmap component doesn't work - Primefaces 3.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378153/binding-of-pgmap-component-doesnt-work-primefaces-3-4-1) Problem was solved by adding
`<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="gmap/gmap.js" />`